# Trouble looping through array, avoid adding ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

## Looking to:

Have the data for each of the 56 people show up in a popup window/ "tooltip" when you click on the image of their face (see `index.html`) without having to use ids. For example, clicking on Allan's image should give you her data stored in `var MLA` tried using a for loop to little success, maybe .each()

There are two MLAs here in the example, `scripts.js`, but there are actually a total of 56 items that I'm trying to iterate over. Right, now I'm getting the last person in the array.

### scripts.js (Data, attempted for loop)

```
    // MLAs
         var MLAs = [
           {
             "Name": "Nancy Allan",
             "Age": 62,
             "Constuency": "St. Vital",
             "Party": "NDP",
             "Gender": "Female",
             "Ethnicity": "White"
           },
           {
             "Name": "James Allum",
             "Age": null,
             "Constuency": "Fort Garry-Riverview",
             "Party": "NDP",
             "Gender": "Male",
             "Ethnicity": "White"
           }]

     // Shows a popup with MLA information
     $(".headshot").click(function(){
          $(".tooltip").css("display", "block");
          for (i = 0; i < 56; i++) {
              $(".tooltipName").html(MLAs[i].Name);
              $(".tooltipParty").html(MLAs[i].Party);
              $(".tooltipConstuency").html(MLAs[i].Constuency);
              $(".tooltipEthnicity").html(MLAs[i].Ethnicity) + ",";
              $(".tooltipAge").html(MLAs[i].Age);
          }
     });
});
```

### Using #ids

Doesn't really solve the problem, is there a better solution?

#### index.html

```
<img src="assets/img/headshots/allan.jpg" id="0" alt="" class="headshot NDP Female White">
<img src="assets/img/headshots/allum.jpg" id="1" alt="" class="headshot NDP Male White">
<img src="assets/img/headshots/altemeyer.jpg" id="2" alt="" class="headshot NDP Male White">
```

#### scripts.js

```
$(".headshot").click(function(){
        index = this.id;

        $(".tooltip").css("display", "block");
            $(".tooltipName").html(MLAs[index].Name);
            $(".tooltipParty").html(MLAs[index].Party);
            $(".tooltipConstuency").html(MLAs[index].Constuency);
            $(".tooltipEthnicity").html(MLAs[index].Ethnicity); + ","
            $(".tooltipAge").html(MLAs[index].Age);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use numeric `id` attribute values. You could simply use their .index() within a selector.

```
<div id="people">
<img src="assets/img/headshots/allan.jpg" alt="" class="headshot NDP Female White">
<img src="assets/img/headshots/allum.jpg" alt="" class="headshot NDP Male White">
...
</div>
```

-

```
$(".headshot").on('click', function() {
    var idx = $(this).index();
    $(".tooltip").css("display", "block");
        $(".tooltipName").html(MLAs[idx].Name);
        $(".tooltipParty").html(MLAs[idx].Party);
        $(".tooltipConstuency").html(MLAs[idx].Constuency);
        $(".tooltipEthnicity").html(MLAs[idx].Ethnicity); + ","
        $(".tooltipAge").html(MLAs[idx].Age);
    });
});
```

Comment: It was working for a bit, now I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined"

Comment: It sounds like a simple data inconsistency. Can you make a jsfiddle for me to look at?

Comment: Cool :) If my answer was most helpful to you, would you mind accepting it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data attribute as described in the [following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) article.

I have provided the code snippet to review.
Please notice that I added key to the JSON data to uniquely identify the record.
If you can not do it, you can create a map[key:JsonObject] instead.

```js
var MLAs = [{
  "Key": "allan",
  "Name": "Nancy Allan",
  "Age": 62,
  "Constuency": "St. Vital",
  "Party": "NDP",
  "Gender": "Female",
  "Ethnicity": "White"
}, {
  "Key": "allum",
  "Name": "James Allum",
  "Age": null,
  "Constuency": "Fort Garry-Riverview",
  "Party": "NDP",
  "Gender": "Male",
  "Ethnicity": "White"
}];

function findObj(key) {
  var result = null;
  $.each(MLAs, function(i, obj) {
    if (obj.Key == key) result = obj;
  });
  return result;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".headshot").click(function() {
    var key = $(this).data('key');
    var obj = findObj(key);
    if (obj != null) {
      $(".tooltip").css("display", "block");
      $(".tooltipName").html(obj.Name);
      $(".tooltipParty").html(obj.Party);
      $(".tooltipConstuency").html(obj.Constuency);
      $(".tooltipEthnicity").html(obj.Ethnicity); + ","
      $(".tooltipAge").html(obj.Age);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-j10EGNjCpSg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAE0/QQmvymOupfE/photo.jpg?sz=32" data-key="allan" class="headshot NDP Female White">
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/368596193089a24f609307b3af288ae6?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" data-key="allum" class="headshot NDP Male White">


<table class="tooltip">
  <tr>
    <td class="tooltipName"></td>
    <td class="tooltipParty"></td>
    <td class="tooltipConstuency"></td>
    <td class="tooltipEthnicity"></td>
    <td class="tooltipAge"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```